# Proper way of reading in files from a directory using Python 2.6 in bash shell

Tags: python, bash, hadoop, mapreduce, file-handling

I am trying to read in files for text processing.

The idea is to run them through Hadoop pseudo distributed file system on my virtual machine using map-reduce code that I am writing. The interface is Ubuntu Linux, I am running Python 2.6 with the installation. I need to use `sys.stdin` for reading in the files, and `sys.stdout` so I pass from mapper to reducer.

Here is my test code for the mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import string
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob(sys.stdin)
for file in files:
    with open(file) as infile:
        txt = infile.read()
        txt = txt.split()
    print(txt)
```

I'm not sure how glob works with `sys.stdin` and I get the following errors:

After testing with piping:

```
[training@localhost data]$ cat test | ./mapper.py
```

I get this:

```
cat: test: Is a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mapper.py", line 8, in <module>
    files = glob.glob(sys.stdin)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/glob.py", line 16, in glob
    return list(iglob(pathname))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/glob.py", line 24, in iglob
    if not has_magic(pathname):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/glob.py", line 78, in has_magic
    return magic_check.search(s) is not None
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

For the moment, I am just trying to read in three small `.txt` files in one directory.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to say `files = glob.glob("test")` to glob files in `test` directory.

Comment: I would like to specify the directory from the command line and not having to go in to the code and change it each time I want to run it on something different, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still I do not fully understand what is your expected output (list or plain
text), the following would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, glob

dir = sys.stdin.read().rstrip('\r\n')
files = glob.glob(dir + '/*')
for file in files:
    with open(file) as infile:
        txt = infile.read()
        txt = txt.split()
    print(txt)
```

Then execute with:

```
echo "test" | ./mapper.py
```

My recommendation is to feed the directory name via the command line argument, not via the stdin as above.
If you want to tweak the format of the output, please let me know.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That does work. I am outputting a dictionary with file names and word lists. I think I can do that part. At least I can do it in a Windows system easy enough. This was just a skeleton routine for reading files in and iterating through them. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad if I could be your help. Good luck for your next challenge!

Answer (score 0):

files = os.listdir(path)

Use this to list all files and then apply for loop.

Comment: So when I want to glob files from a different path, then I would have to go into the program and edit that, then. I was trying to avoid that.